# Can I replace an older version of Jquery with 1.11.3?

Tags: jquery, cdn

I am doing maintenance of an old website and noticed that it serves a local copy of jquery-1.8.2.min.js.  I would like to replace it with a CDN version (probably Google?) to improve site performance.  Should I link to the 1.8.2 version of the Google jquery file or can I jump to 1.11.3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Usually it shouldn't be problem, unless you used very old features that have been removed between those version.

For that reason it's also wise to update more often, so the risk of things breaking is smaller, and it's easier to read about any features being removed between just two versions.

Comment: Thank you.  Not sure why the question got downvoted :\

Answer (score 2):

There are many changes made between version 1.8.x and the current one, most notably for [jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#changes-of-note-in-jquery-1-9)

There is a plugin availabe to simplify the transition from older versions of jQuery https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme

Having said that, you should ALWAYS fully test your code in a development / test environment to ensure this upgrade does not break anything. Also - as the main reason for asking seems to be 'performance', there may not be a direct gain from upgrading. (Don't fix what is not broken, unless there are other pressing reasons).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  In addition to performance, my other concern was that Google was going to stop serving the older versions at some point, and then the site would be totally broken.  I'm not always going to be in charge of maintaining it, so I want to leave it working for as long as possible.